# Can the curvature of space-time be also described as a 'frame' (space) whirlpool?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, kerr-metric, frame-dragging

Can the curvature of space-time be also described as a 'frame' (space) wirlpool?

When we talk about the Schwarzschild metric it can be immagined as a curved manifold but in the Kerr metric it seams like it is a whirlpool-like 'curvature' where the movement of the frame looks to work as gravity while the mass is just moving at constant speed inside that frame. So it is possible that gravitationally induced movement of the mass is just the constant movement of the mass inside the frame added to the accelerating movement of the frame which really looks like a whirlpool and the sum is the overall velocity... So the speed of e.g. an accretion disk could be more than the speed of light...

Comment: It's hard to answer since you appear to be using the word 'frame' in a particular way. Perhaps if you defined more fully what you mean by 'frame' it would help. But regarding the last part, any light moving next to massive particles in an accretion disk will certainly catch up and overtake the particles.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not quite as you described. This model is called the river model and is described in the paper “The River Model of Black Holes” by Hamilton and Lisle: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411060

Note, one huge caveat to this method is that it does not generalize. It works for Schwarzschild and Kerr black hole spacetimes only, not for general spacetimes. So you cannot consider it a general model for “how the world works”.

That caveat aside, the Kerr river model is quite interesting. It does not result in a whirlpool. The “river” for the Kerr river model still flows directly in towards the singularity. Instead, at each location in the inflowing river there is a spin. Instead of the Kerr river twisting in like a whirlpool it flows directly in while spinning. Space is pulled inward and spun, and then matter moves according to the rules of special relativity in that space.

Comment: Could this 'river' somehow change direction due to difference in 'pressure' and be ejected at the poles dragging particles as an astrophysical jet?      (Asking in lack of other different presumtions...)

Comment: No. Please read the paper before further speculation. Again, this is **not** “how the world works”. It is a heuristic that works as is only for the Schwarzschild and Kerr metrics. It cannot be generally changed or adapted to other spacetimes.